# How to create 4 headers such that it becomes header rows for 16 columns in pandas dataframe in CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

This is the input csv and the 4 header rows are becoming header for last 4 columns but I want that 1 header becomes header for first 4 columns (Client, DII, FII and Pro). Likewise 2nd header for another 4 columns in CSV format in pandas dataframe:-
How to create 4 header rows such that it occupies 4 cells?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html):

```
In [2965]: a = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["X"], df.columns[:2]])

In [2966]: b = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Y"], df.columns[2:]])

In [2975]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a.tolist() + b.tolist())

In [2976]: df 
Out[2976]: 
   X     Y   
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: @AyushAnand Let me know if the answer helped.

Comment: No bro it didn't work. I updated my question. Please check it once.

Comment: This looks like a different question from yesterday bro.

Comment: yeah my bad I thought it is similar to the  one I posted yesterday. Can u tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html)

```
a = np.repeat(['X','Y'],2)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(a,df.columns))
df
   X     Y   
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4
```